# The =IF function in Excel 2010 is saying it does not work?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Well, this is a simple question really.

In Excel 2010, why isn't the =IF function working?
What I am typing in is:

```
=IF(OR(G5:W13=20),"","$20")
```

What I am trying to do is if any cell between the area of G5 and W13 has the exact value of $20 (all of the cells are set to text format Currency, before anyone corrects me) it will show nothing. Though if there isn't any cells that have the value of $20, it will just show $20 on that particular cell.

After experimenting, the culprit is it saying `G5:W13`. I'm okay typing all the cells between that area, so I did do that. However, it tells me that I have an error in my formula when I do that, so therefore I am stuck.

Is there a way from it to stop correcting either of those?
All help is appreciated. :)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/420344-how-do-i-have-a-formula-check-if-a-value-occurs-within-a-range.html

Comment: I'm sure the error is not *"it does not work"*. As you only have a single parameter in the `OR` function (rather than some `OR(condition1, condition2, condition3, ...)`): did you use an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)? (And as an aside: you might not want to include the `$` if you already formatted all cells as Currency.)

Comment: As Arjan as indicated, it is the `OR()` function that is being used incorrectly in this instance. AFAIK if you specify a range as one of the (upto 30) conditionals then this must be used alone, not as part of an expression. I would do the same as Amer in his answer and use `COUNTIF` instead (+1).

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the `=OR()` with `=COUNTIF`, and it is working like a charm. Thank you so very much. :) Oh, and just to clarify, Arjan, the one that had the $ at the front wasn't in currency. The first 20 was. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. If @Amer's answer worked for you then you can _accept_ his answer (informs others that the question has a solution).

Comment: @w3d, the `OR` [can be used](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/or-function-HP010062403.aspx) to find a value in an array, *if* entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter. OpenOffice.org will then *display* it with curly braces, as `{=IF(OR(G5:W13=20),"","$20")}`; not sure about Excel. (Not that such is the best solution for this problem.) Mordecaii, why not format the result cell as Currency as well, and output the *number* `20` rather than some text `"$20"`? Chances are that one day you might want to use that result in some other calculations. Don't use text where it's not really text.

Comment: (Please, see also [replying in comments](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-reply).)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, you are absolutely correct. An array formula works in this instance as well, as you have mentioned. And is indeed displayed with surrounding curly braces in Excel (as in OpenOffice).

Comment: Wow, as for outputting a number rather than some text like I commented above: [there you have it](http://superuser.com/questions/585650/on-excel-2010-the-countif-function-displaying-the-value-improperly)...

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(G5:W13, 20), "", "$20")`

This counts the number of instances of 20 in the desired range, if greater than zero it will show "$20"