# On Excel 2010, the =COUNTIF function displaying the value improperly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Well, here is the code I am using below:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G5:W13,"10"),"","$10")
```

This code is working perfectly fine, however the number is not actually been treated as a number.

I have done a number of those codes, with different cash amounts shown. Then, a certain cell displays the average of those cash amounts.

The average appears up as `#DIV/0!`, which I'm guessing is that the numbers shown aren't been treated as numbers, instead, they are being treated as words. Therefore not displaying the average.

Is there a way to maybe alter the before formula, and make it think that $10 is a number?
Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Drop the `$` and format the cell as currency? Or perhaps further: `=IF(COUNTIF(G5:W13,"10"),"",10)`

Comment: I got rid of the quotation marks of the last `10`, however now it is shown as `$10.00`. I only want it shown as `$10`, so would that be fixable? I do have to admit though, I would have never found that out. Thanks. :)

Comment: Format Cell => Currency => Decimal Places: 0

Comment: @ta.speot.is you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, drop the formatting from your code and just specify a value instead. Leave the formatting to Excel.

So, you'll want either:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G5:W13,"10"),"","10")
```

or possibly:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G5:W13,"10"),"",10)
```

After that, use the *Currency* cell format, and adjust its options as necessary (e.g. set an appropriate value for *Decimal Places*):

[image: Format Cells]